# How do I import other scripts?

Tags: python, file, import

OK, I tried looking up the question but I'm getting a lot of answers that confuse me(sorry for my ignorance). I wrote a script, and I want to import another script so that when i run it in the terminal it will be as if the second script is part of the first. How do I do this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you want `a.py` to use `b.py`. If the code in `b.py` is written outside of any function or class, all you need to do to run it is simply:

```
import b
```

If however the code is in some function, for example:

```
# Code in b.py
def some_func():
    # Implementation
```

Then you'll need to either:

```
import b
b.some_func()
```

or:

```
from b import some_func
some_func()
```

Finally, if you're code is in a function in a class, for example:

```
# Code in b.py
class ClassB():
    def some_func(self):
        # Implementation
```

you can:

```
from b import ClassB
obj_b = ClassB()
obj_b.some_func()
```

Comment: May be valuable to explain where these files should be in the filesystem (in the same folder) for the example `import` statements to work. Your call.

Comment: @Jeff - I think it's off topic and justifies a dedicated question

Answer (score 2):

If you want the script to just be inserted inline (like a #include), then you're Doing It Wrong.

This will import all of the symbols from your other script as if they were defined locally (with the exception that global variable access in the imported code will be scoped to the imported module, not the local module).

```
from OtherScript import *
```

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: The part that says `as if defined locally` is incorrect.  The names will be imported into the local namespace, but if they access any globals it will be the imported module's globals, not the local module's globals.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Noted, although from the point of view of the code doing the importing that doesn't really matter. The symbols that are imported will appear in the local namespace as if they had been defined locally regardless of how the imported code functions internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script named `first.py`:

```
def print_something():
    print("something")
```

You can then `import` that from another script (in the same directory):

```
import first

first.print_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Import, so if the other script is named FirstScrity.py

```
import FirstScript
```

To use something from that script you have to do FirstScript."NAME OF THING TO USE"

If your dont wanna do that you can do

```
from FirstScript import "NAME OF THING TO USE"
```

or

```
from FirstScript import *
```